# MySQL join show all rows only from left table

Tags: mysql, join

I have this MySQL select with Join:

```
select 
`imagefolders`.*, `conventionreports`.`publicationdate`
from `imagefolders` 
left join `conventionreports` 
on `imagefolders`.`id` = `conventionreports`.`imagegallery_id` 
where `imagefolders`.`deleted_at` is null 
and `imagefolders`.`is_conv_gallery` = 1 
order by `conventionreports`.`publicationdate` desc
```

The sql should only show rows from the left table (imagefolders) and should add a field "publicationdate" from the right table (conventionreports).

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add both table's data and desired output result ?

Comment: here https://paste.laravel.io/3X05Z

Comment: for better,you should try here http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: sorry I don't know how to work with that :-(